# Determine The Bit Depth of a DynamicImage in Rust

Tags: rust

How could one determine the bit depth of a `image::DynamicImage` in rust? I'm using [fltk-rs](https://docs.rs/fltk/0.11.6/fltk/) [function](https://docs.rs/fltk/0.11.6/fltk/image/struct.RgbImage.html) for creating an `RgbImage`and `RgbImage::new()` requires that I specify the bit depth of the Rgb byte data its going to be created from. The images I'm loading in my program have various bit depths, so I need to be able to determine the bit depth value for image dynamically.

```
impl RgbImage

pub fn new(
    data: &[u8],
    w: u32,
    h: u32,
    depth: u32
) -> Result<RgbImage, FltkError>
```

Here's a typical use case where I would like to know the bit depth of my DynamicImage:

```
image = "0.23.12"
fltk = "0.12.0"
```

```rust
use image::*;
use fltk::*;
//...
let img = image::open("my_img.png").unwrap(); //<---find the bit depth of this loaded image
let (imgx, imgy) = img.dimensions();
let fltk_rgb = RgbImage::new(&img.to_bytes(), imgx, imgy, 4).unwrap(); //<---then use bit depth value here
//...
```

Comment: `DynamicImage` is an enum, you can `match` on it.

Comment: @IvanC match by the bit depth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ivan C said, the easiest way is with a look-up table in a `match` statement.

```rust
use image::DynamicImage;

pub fn bit_depth(image: &image::DynamicImage) -> u32 {
    use DynamicImage::*;

    match image {
        ImageLuma8(_) => 1,
        ImageLumaA8(_) => 2,
        ImageRgb8(_) => 3,
        ImageRgba8(_) => 4,
        ImageBgr8(_) => 3,
        ImageBgra8(_) => 4,
        ImageLuma16(_) => 2,
        ImageLumaA16(_) => 4,
        ImageRgb16(_) => 6,
        ImageRgba16(_) => 8,
    }
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=21c82d7bb90d4d04d47e9be716f88297)

That said, you'll have to be a little bit careful. FLTK makes some assumptions about what the bit depth says about color order in each pixel (documented [here](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/classFl__RGB__Image.html), note in particular that it assumes RGB color order and will reject any bit depths >4). It might be better to create a function that takes a `DynamicImage` and converts it if necessary to the appropriate FLTK-compatible representation in the `image` crate (essentially one of ImageLuma8, ImageLumaA8, ImageRgb8 or ImageRgba8), then hard-codes the bit depth for the resulting image type.

Answer (score 2):

`DynamicImage` has a [`color()`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.14/image/enum.DynamicImage.html#method.color) method to get the color type, which itself has a [`bytes_per_pixel()`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.14/image/enum.ColorType.html#method.bytes_per_pixel) method:

```
img.color().bytes_per_pixel()
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a good reminder that it is always worth looking at other answers rather than just the accepted one.