# Determine if loaded image has alpha channel using Rust image crate

Tags: rust

For the purposes of drawing images into a GUI, I need to determine if an image has an alpha channel. [I've asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65556984/determine-the-bit-depth-of-a-dynamicimage-in-rust) in regards to getting the bit depth of an `image::DynamicImage`,
but was wondering if the image crate has any other means of detecting an alpha channel for a `DynamicImage` other than using such a match statement.

```
image = "0.23.14"
```

```rust
use image::*;
use image::io::Reader as ImageReader;

fn main(){
    let loaded_img: DynamicImage = ImageReader::open(path).unwrap().decode().unwrap();  
    dbg!(is_rgba(loaded_img));
}

fn has_alpha(img: DynamicImage) -> bool{
    match img {
        DynamicImage::ImageLumaA8(_) => true,
        DynamicImage::ImageRgba8(_) => true,
        DynamicImage::ImageBgra8(_) => true,
        DynamicImage::ImageLumaA16(_) => true,
        DynamicImage::ImageRgba16(_) => true,
        _=>false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DynamicImage` has a [`color()`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.14/image/enum.DynamicImage.html#method.color) method to get the color type, which itself has a [`has_alpha()`](https://docs.rs/image/0.23.14/image/enum.ColorType.html#method.has_alpha) method:

```
fn has_alpha(img: DynamicImage) -> bool {
    img.color().has_alpha()
}
```

Comment: ```has_alpha(ImageReader::open("my_image.png").unwrap().decode().unwrap())``` returns false for me. Shouldn't it return true for all pngs? I believe there are no transparent pixels in the image itself, would this effect the return value of ```has_alpha()```?

Comment: No, not all pngs have an alpha channel.

Comment: @ANimator120 the absence or presence of transparency in the image would not necessarily change the return value of has_alpha, but I would expect the average PNG exporter or compressor to only use a color type with alpha sample if the image *needs* it, so... kind-of? e.g. why would photoshop save to a heavier RGBA when RGB or even palletized suffices?